# change href with jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to change href tag with jquery, now i've got this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hScreen = $(window).height();
    var lScreen = $(window).width();

    if(hScreen < 800){

    }
});
```

now i want to see if hScreen is less than 800 my href will be:

```
<a href="javascript:" onClick="window.open('v2/main.html','longu','width='+screen.availWidth,'height='+screen.availHeight,scrollbars=1); return false;" >
```

else if hScreen is more i must see this:

```
<a href="main.htm">
```

thx for your help!!

Comment: Everybody's typing as fast as they can ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give your link an id (for example id="aDeneme") then;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hScreen = $(window).height();
    var lScreen = $(window).width();
 if(hScreen < 800){
$("aDeneme").attr("href","javascript:void(0)");
$("aDeneme").attr("onclick","window.open('v2/main.html','longu','width='+screen.availWidth,'height='+screen.availHeight,scrollbars=1)");
    }
else{
$("aDeneme").attr("href","main.htm");
}
```

Comment: it works, but the window.open now don't open a window with screen Height but a window with 200px height

Answer (score 6):

use **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```
if(hScreen < 800){
   $('a').attr('href','main.htm');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way i can think of this

```
$("selector for your anchor tag").attr('href',value);
```

Decide your value based on the condition

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will work for you

```
$(function(){
  var hScreen = $(window).height();
  var lScreen = $(window).width();

  function checkHeight(){
    if(hScreen < 800){
      window.open('v2/main.html','longu','width='+screen.availWidth,'height='+screen.availHeight,scrollbars=1);
    } else {
      window.open('main.html');
    }
  }
})

<a href="checkHeight();">
```

Answer (score 1):

give it a unique id and add/remove attributes.

```
<a id="myLink" href="javascript:"></a>
```

in jquery you will do

```
$('#myLink').attr('href', 'main.htm');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="main.htm" id="mainLink">Goto to main Link</a>
```

Here `id="mainLink"` is required to select this element from JavaScript

**JavaScript code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hScreen = $(window).height();
    var lScreen = $(window).width();

    if(hScreen < 800) {
       $("#mainLink").bind('click', function() {
         window.open('v2/main.html', 'longu', 'width=' + screen.availWidth, 'height=' + screen.availHeight, scrollbars=1);
         return false;
       });
    }
});
```

This should be it, if you have `hScreen < 800`, you bind the click event to open up a pop up window otherwise just use `href`

Comment: it works, but the javascript href don't open a ScreenHeight window